# Why are my forked processes being killed?

Tags: perl, fork

I'm running on a Red Hat RHEL 7.9 server.  I have a Perl script which repeatedly calls fork() to run several hundred different small C-based programs. It only runs about 10 programs at a time (my machine has 16 cores) and then waits for a previous program to finish before calling fork() to start a new one. Most of the programs finish within 10 seconds.

After a few minutes, many of these programs are being killed. If I run the outer Perl script again and again, a different number of programs are killed, and different individual programs are killed.  Also, if I decrease the number of concurrent programs, then the number of killed programs decrease significantly (so it could be a resource problem).  I don't know why the programs are being killed.  All I see is this error message in the console window (where XXXXXX is the PID):

```
sh: line 1: XXXXXX Killed                  ProgName
```

How can I find out why these programs are being killed? Or, how can I stop them from being killed, or research this myself?

Comment: Have you run `strace` on it?

Comment: No, I don't have strace on that system.

Comment: Does it also happen if you use `system()` instead of `fork()` and `exec()`?

Comment: I don't know how to replace fork() with system() in this case.  I have to fork a new process and get the PID of the child process.  Can I do that with system()?

Comment: Use the `free` command to see if you have any swap space. You should have at least 1xRAM.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ulimit -a` to your question?

Comment: This machine has no 'ulimit'.

Comment: There's about 2 gigabytes of swap space.

Comment: @JB_User: ulimit is a shell builtin in bash, zsh, dash, ksh, and busybox. In tcsh it's `limit`.

Comment: Okay.  Here'es the ulimit output: core file size 0
data seg size: unlimited
scheduling priority: 0
file size: unlimited
pending signals: 1414972
max locked memory: unlimited
max memory size: unlimited
open files: 16384
pipe size: 8
POSIX message queues: 819200
real-time priority: 0
stack size: unlimited
cpu time: 86400
max user processes: 4096
virtual memory: unlimited
file locks: unlimited

Comment: Max user processes 4096 seems low; that could be it. You can count how many processes your user is running with something like `ps -U <username> -u <username> | wc -l`.